# I'm trying to pass an initial state to createStore, but it doesn't seem to do initialize with an empty state anyway

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I have a page with about 15 components. At any different scenario, only some components show (there are about 5 different possible combination of components based on what the current state is).

I want to test that the components do show/hide when needed, so in my tests, I wrap the parent component (the page) in a provider. For each one of the scenarios, I want to pass to the provider a store with a different initial state, so I could then check which component show and which don't.

Yet, when I run the tests they fail, and by printing the state in the page component, I can see that the initial state is just an empty state tree. How can I successfully set the state to what I need it to be?

In my tests, I have this setup function:

```
const setup = (initialState: RootState) => {
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState);
  return mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <UserDashboardContainer />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

This is a sample of one of my tests

```
  test("Test that the right components show", () => {
    const wrapper = setup(scenarioTwoState);

    expect(wrapper.find(`[data-test="user-dashboard-container"]`)).toHaveLength(
      1
    );
    expect(
      wrapper.find(`[data-test="dashboard-dna-kit-tracker"]`)
    ).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(wrapper.find(`[data-test="dashboard-add-more-files"]`)).toHaveLength(
      1
    );
    expect(wrapper.find(`[data-test="dashboard-profiles"]`)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
```

Where scenarioTwoState is this:

```
export const scenarioTwoState: RootState = {
  user: { id: "UID1", email: "user@email.com", activeProfile: null },
  activeUserProfile: null,
  userSubscription: {
    id: "USID1",
    subscriptionType: "yearly",
    isExpired: false,
  },
  tables: {
    articles: {
      entities: {},
      ids: [],
      status: "idle",
    },
    dnaKits: { entities: {}, ids: [], status: "idle" },
    genomeFiles: { entities: {}, ids: [], status: "idle" },
    orders: {
      entities: {
        OID1: {
          id: "OID1",
          paid: true,
          status: "received",
          orderDateTime: 3432,
          products: [
            {
              id: "KID1",
              stage: "shipped",
              paid: true,
              profileId: null,
              fileId: null,
              isNew: false,
            },
          ],
        },
      },
      ids: ["OID1"],
      status: "fulfilled",
    },
    unclaimedOrders: { entities: {}, ids: [], status: "idle" },
    userProfiles: { entities: {}, ids: [], status: "idle" },
    wellnessReports: { entities: {}, ids: [], status: "idle" },
  },
};
```

as I've mentioned though, when I print the state from the parent component (and check it in the terminal where I run my test), it prints this (empty state tree):

```
{
  user: null,
  userSubscription: null,
  activeUserProfile: null,
  tables: {
    articles: { ids: [], entities: {}, status: "idle" },
    dnaKits: { ids: [], entities: {}, status: "idle" },
    genomeFiles: { ids: [], entities: {}, status: "idle" },
    orders: { ids: [], entities: {}, status: "idle" },
    unclaimedOrders: { ids: [], entities: {}, status: "idle" },
    userProfiles: { ids: [], entities: {}, status: "idle" },
    wellnessReports: { ids: [], entities: {}, status: "idle" },
  },
};
```